# 指定列が最大値の行を出力したい

Tags: google-spreadsheet

```
month,day,count
10  1   5
10  2   6
11  3   7
11  4   8
```

のような日付ごとの数字データが有って
これを月ごとの最大値を記録した行を出力したいです

求める結果

```
10  2   6
11  4   8
```

１０月は２日に６
１１月は４日に８
と言う感じです

---

月と最大値だけ表にするのは

```
=query(A:C,"select A, max(C) where A IS NOT NULL group by A", false)
```

```
    max     
10  6
11  8
```

とかでできるんですがその最大値を取る日付も出力するのはどうすればできるでしょうか

https://qiita.com/nogitsune413/items/f413268d01b4ea2394b1
SQL だとサブクエリとJOINしたりしてできそうなんですが
スプレッドシートでもやる方法ってありますか？

---

あるいは = query の結果を１列目と３列目のように間をあけて出力することはできないでしょうか

日付は lookup なりを使えば別にうめることはできそうなんですが
query 結果が前２列にうまってしまうので
間の２列目に日付を入れたいです

Answer (score 5, accepted):

下記のようなサンプルはいかがでしょうか。

#### Sample formula:

```
=BYROW(UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A,A2:A<>"")),LAMBDA(R,SORTN(QUERY(A2:C,"SELECT * WHERE A="&R),1,0,3,FALSE)))
```

- 列AからUnique値を取得し、それを使用してグループごとにソートを行い、列Cが最大値の行を取得する流れです。

#### Testing:

表示されている表がヘッダ込みでセル A1:C5 の場合、例えば、セルE2へ上記の式を入れると、下記のような結果が得られます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

#### References:

- [BYROW](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12570930)
- [LAMBDA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718)
- [SORTN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7354624)

Comment: SORTでMAXを取り出すんですね。３つとも使ったことなかったんですがBYROWは他にも応用がききそうです。ありがとうございました。

Comment: @chico ご返事ありがとうございます。BYROWは最近Google SpreadsheetのBuilt-in functionsに加わりました。これまで複雑になったFormulasもこれを使うことでシンプルになることもあり重宝されているようです。加わった当初は使用できるデータ量が少なかったのですが、これについても最近のアップデートで少し解消されたようでより用途が増えそうです。